# Is there any way I can build a RESTful web service to hit Amazon EMR

Tags: api, http, amazon-emr

I am trying to build a backend service which contains an endpoint. This endpoint is supposed to hit Amazon EMR server and run a scala script with provided params. I know we can build services with Amazon Lambda and Amazon API, but is there any way to do the same with EMR?

Comment: have you looked into Apache Livy? https://livy.incubator.apache.org/

Comment: @Bitswazsky yes, I recently came across apache-livy. however I am still struggling with how to connect apache Livy with my web application